# Is there a way to see how much enchantments a piece of armor can hold, before you buy the diagram?

Tags: the-witcher-2

In the game Witcher 2 there are all sorts of enchantments for weapons, armor etc.

Is there a way to see how much enchantments a piece of armor can hold, before you buy the diagram or only when you build it and wear/hold it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to look at the [wiki](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_2_armor) entry for armor. That's got a list of every piece of armor in the game and when you click on those links you can find exactly how many enhancements each will take. If you have any questions about enhancements you can also check [here](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_enhancements#Armor_enhancements). Wikis are your friend.